# Timer in C# to start an alarm - condition to prevent it from starting before 8am

Tags: c#, timer

I am a complete beginner. I am trying to make a simple program (a sort of alarm) that will have an 8 hour timer and when the time elapses it will run an .exe and close itself, but only if the time is 08:00 or later. If the timer elapses between 00:00 and 08:00, I would like it to wait and start the .exe and close itself at 08:00.

Example:

- I start the program at 1am. **At 9am** the timer elapses, runs Alarm.exe
  and closes itself.
- I start the program at 12am. **At 8am** the timer
  elapses, runs Alarm.exe and closes itself.
- I start the program at
  11pm. At 7am the timer elapses, but I would like the program to run
  Alarm.exe and close itself **at 8am**.

My code so far:

```
namespace Timer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()

        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
            TimeSpan eight = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0);
            TimeSpan remaining = eight - now;
            if (now >= eight)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"Alarm.exe");
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
            }
            else
            {
                timer2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(remaining); // this doesn't make any sense I know, I just can't figure out how to make another timer that uses the remaining period.....
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"Alarm.exe");
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help and please be easy on me, I am a complete noob and I've spent over 20 hours on this.

Comment: You could just set the `timer1.Value` in code (instead of designer) in `Load`, to the exact time you need. Or you could restart the timer with `timer1.Value = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(8) - DateTime.Now;`

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you. I just tried it, but it gives me some kind of error that I don't understand. **'Timer' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no accessible extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'Timer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?**

Comment: Sorry `timer1.Interval`

Comment: @Charlieface now it says **Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.TimeSpan' to 'int'** :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your timer again up to the difference between the current time and 8:00

You can change your Timer handler to this:

```cs
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Hour >= 8)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"Alarm.exe");
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Interval = (int) (DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(8) - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wow, such a simple solution and it works like a charm! Thank you so much!